# google-analytics referral traffic different results

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

i have this data in my google-analytics 
ALL » DEFAULT CHANNEL GROUPING: Referral» SOURCE: test.domain.com

```
Referral Path        Users
/2016/02/25/article/ 3819
/2018/02/01/article/ 316
/2018/02/07/article/ 109
```

when i try to get this through analytics reporting v4

```
{
  "reportRequests": 
  [
    {
      "viewId": "XXXXX",
      "dateRanges": [{"startDate": "2018-01-01","endDate": "2018-02-27"}],
      "dimensions":[{"name": "ga:fullReferrer"}],
      "metrics":[{"expression":"ga:users"}],
      "dimensionFilterClauses":[{"filters": 
          [{"dimensionName": "ga:fullReferrer",
            "expressions":["test.domain.com/2016/02/25/article/",
                           "test.domain.com/2018/02/01/article/",
                           "test.domain.com/2018/02/07/article/"
              ],
              "operator": "IN_LIST"
          }]
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

i have got different result

```
Full Referrer        Users
    test.domain.com/2016/02/25/article/ 2015
    test.domain.com/2018/02/01/article/ 208
    test.domain.com/2018/02/07/article/ 82
```

why this happen? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: check the response find the field is golden.  Your data may not have completed processing.

Comment: isDataGolden:true

Comment: We are found a source of problem - it was Sampled Data.
Adds some filters was a decision.
@DaImTo you are was nearly right!
Thank you!